# Social Login Interface on Checkout page

Tags: php, magento

I was trying to add the social login interface on my checkout page, I followed the following process:-

Open `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/login.phtml` to show Social Login interface on checkout page. This file is template file for Checkout page.

Place following code where you want Social Login interface to appear (probably below login form) on this page:-

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('sociallogin/sociallogin')->setTemplate('sociallogin/sociallogincustom.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

If it doesn’t work then place the above mentioned code in the following file:-

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
```

I did not succeed with this steps.

I tried adding a widget on the checkout page. I was working now but It is a mess on my checkout page.

Can you please let me know where is the code for checkout page so that I can edit it.

Comment: Do you want to allow user to login using social sites and where exactly you want the social login button?

Comment: I want it below my Login information.